# can i zoom the image in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

i want to know how to zoom the image in iframe.

for example i have to view the image as 50% zoom,75% zoom and 100% zoom.

is this possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that you want to resize the contents of the iframe to a percentage? Do you want this to be done with Javascript, or while loading the page?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS 3 property called "zoom" that you can put on most elements:

http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/

in IE7 and earlier you need to use the "-ms-zoom" CSS extension:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(VS.85).aspx

Just want to add that the other poster's choice of using width/height with % value is definitely preferred for images. The zoom property is only really useful if you need a laytout that contains multiple items to scale/zoom together. (e.g. putting the zoom on a div that contains other elements, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The vars `yd` and `ye` below are YUI 2.8.1 dependency files for Dom and Event, you could achieve the same effect without YUI. I'm basically just setting the `zoom` CSS level on the image when I click (the zoom value is obtained simply from the text value of the link I click).

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="zoom">25</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="zoom">50</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="zoom">100</a>

<img src="content/img/1000-1-people.png" width="350" height="290" alt="" id="myImage" />

<script type="text/javascript">
ye.on( yd.getElementsByClassName('zoom', null, document), 'click', function(e){
    yd.setStyle(yd.get('myImage'), 'zoom', this.innerHTML+'%');
});
</script>
```